# How to check if form control is valid in Angular programatically?

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

I need to check in the component (not in the template) if a control generated by formBuilder is valid. I tried:

```
if(this.miSpecialForm.controls.miName.dirty){
 console.log('Hi mom!');
}
```

but I get the error:

```
Property 'miName' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
this.miSpecialForm.get('miName').valid
```

Answer (score 8):

```
if(this.miSpecialForm.controls['miName'].valid){
     console.log('Hi mom!');
}
```